# Dropdown menu filter - show only checkbox list

Tags: handsontable

I've found this example in the documentation which shows a custom drop down menu with only the filter by value condition:
https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.2.0/demo-filtering.html#dropdown

The dropdown menu items are set explicitly by passing values to the dropdownMenu array:

`dropdownMenu: ['filter_by_condition', 'filter_action_bar']`

But I only want to show the "checkbox list" (under select all) in the dropdown menu as in this example: 
https://handsontable.com/examples.html?_ga=2.38233699.1704423548.1502423159-1885395872.1502423159&headers&filters

Is there a value I can pass to the drodownMenu array (or some other means) to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep.
You can do it like this:

```
dropdownMenu: ['filter_by_condition', 'filter_by_value', 'filter_action_bar'],
```

Boom. *Done*.

*Note:* I am using HOT pro @

- Version: 4.0.0
- Release date: 13/06/2018 (built at 13/06/2018 12:28:08)